# How do I get Android Studio to point to my SDK source code?

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio debugger is pointing to the wrong version of the SDK source code, so I cannot step through system code. How do I make it use a particular SDK source path?

To be clear: it is pointing at the right SDK, but the wrong version of SDK source code (16 instead of 17).

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It's sort-of confusing but there's two settings for Android SDK in Android Studio (AT). When you go to module settings->Android SDK, that's your general SDK directory. But go to module settings->Android SDK, and click on the module for your app. if you're using 0.4.2, you should see under the properties tab, a few entries: compile sdk version is one of those entries. You can set it to 19.0, 18.0, 17.0, etc, whatever you want.

Comment: Sigh... Thank you but I'm using 0.3.1. Upgrading is currently not an option. :( I don't see the settings you're talking about. Are you referring to the Project Structure dialog?

Comment: open all your `build.gradle` files and change `compileSdkVersion` to 19 and let me know if it solves your problem.