# Merge (Conference) calls for rooted phone

Tags: android

I am facing a problem which is to merge (Conference) two or more calls programmatically. After studying so many threads on stack overflow and group google, I have come on the conclusion that Its not possible because of private API. On contrary I have read, merging is possible in rooted phones. Can anyone help me how to achieve merge call on rooted phone? And how I can make those private packages accessible for rooted phone.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd guess you have to use the SUPERUSER permission, and call the internal API using reflection. You'd have to figure out what method is called to initiate the merge call, by the Android system itself. I guess you'd have to debug it for that.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you please give me an example for that.

Comment: I've never done that before. But this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174980/how-do-i-get-android-studio-to-point-to-my-sdk-source-code and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295873/how-do-i-request-root-access-in-android